# Problemas con scroll en MODAL

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, bootstrap, modal

Buen día

Estoy desarrollando un modulo donde al hacer clic a un botón, se abre un modal, el cual sirve para realizar una búsqueda de llantas, al mostrar los resultados conectados con base de datos, el modal se le habilita un scroll para poder ver todos los resultados verticalmente. Y para ver los detalles de esa llanta, se le hace clic a un botón "Detalles" que se imprime junto a cada resultado. Al hacer clic en el botón "Detalles", se abre un segundo modal. Al momento de abrir el segundo modal, cierro el primer modal con este código:

```
$("#btnCerrarLlantas").click();
```

Luego de cerrar el segundo modal, vuelvo abrir el primer modal:

```
$("#btnAbrirModalVehiculo").click();
```

Cuando abro el primer modal nuevamente, ejecuto nuevamente el query que se realizo antes de cerrar el primer modal, para que el usuario pueda seguir viendo los resultados que tenia antes de haber cerrado el primer modal.

El detalle es que al momento de cerrar y abrir el modal nuevamente, el scroll del primer modal, deja de funcionar, no me permite ver el modal completo, se queda como estatico.

Gracias por adelantado.

Comment: Que comando utilizas para abrir el modal?

Comment: Mando a llamar al modal con esto


`<a href="#" id="btnAbrirModalVehiculo" class="txt-black" style="text-decoration:none;" data-toggle="modal" data-target=".v1" data-backdrop="false">
     <img src="img/auto.png" alt="" class=" img-fluid mx-auto d-block"/>
</a>`

Answer (score 1):

Solamente le agregue en el div del primer modal el siguiente codigo:

```
style="overflow-y: scroll;"
```